# Using Riesz tranform to proof a inequality

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Here's the statement of the problem:

Let $p \in (1, \infty)$. Prove that there exists $C > 0$ such that $\forall f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{C}\sum_{j=1}^d \|\partial_j f\|_p \le \|\sqrt{-\Delta}f \|_p \le C\sum_{j=1}^d\| \partial_j f \|_p
\end{eqnarray}

Here's the idea, but I cannot fill out the details. Any helps or suggestions will be appreciated.

First, we consider $d = 1$.

Next,for $d \ge 1$, consider symbol $m_j(\xi)$ = $\frac{\xi_j}{\lvert \xi \rvert}$, and $T_jf = \check{m} \ast f$, check that $T_j \in B(L^p(\mathbb{R}^d))$.

Show that $T_j \sim \frac{\partial_j}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}$.

Then, need Riesz transform(some explanation about this transform will be great).
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{-\Delta}f = (\xi \mapsto \lvert\xi\rvert\hat{f}(\xi))\check{}
\end{eqnarray}

If possible, need some information about how to start such a question, and how to find the constant C. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try the book of Elias Stein, Singular Integrals and Differentiability properties of functions, chp. V.